# FeedWord Press - Media attachments

Tags: wordpress

I installed the FeedWordpress plugin but I noticed it was not posting the images in the media attachment of the feeds, but only the text. I found a little script that helped me a bit (the images are added to a custom field without actually downloading them). The problem is I need thumbnail images and of course.. you can't have thumbnail images without downloading the image.

Is there any way I could download automatically the images in the media attachments ? Or, is there any other way I could have my thumbnails fixed ?

I would honestly appreciate any help

rss feed: http://www.antena3.ro/rss/politica.xml

my website: http://www.rolportal.info

Answer (score 0):

I am major armature in the developer domain, however, my PHP guy sorted it out by downloading another plugin called Auto Post Thumbnail, they did a small hack so it would constantly check for feature images.

You have to make sure you sure your CSS person tells the feature image grabber to only grab images of a certain size, and crop if necessary, this will prevent it pulling social media icons in as feature images :)

**I did have a duplicating image problem recently, i disabled Jetpack which fixed the problem, but I want Jetpack back :(

Good luck, if you need more detailed information, I will ask my developer.

Sincerely,

Brook